# x non-numeric argument to binary operator while using mutate

Tags: r

Trying to add a column to data frame I have created using mutate function

```
names <- c("anup", "minal", "surya", "sheetal")
age <- c("26", "27", "28", "30")
people <- data.frame(names, age)

mutate(people, age_in_20 = age + 20)
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `age_in_20`. i `age_in_20 = age
>
> - 20`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator

Where I go wrong?

Comment: Don't put quotes around the numbers in ``age <- c("26", "27", "28", "30")`` - it's making them characters rather than numbers.

Comment: @anupkumar karanje , you should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You defined **age** as characters. Write :

`age <- c(26,27,28,30)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix that number-as-character issue on the fly, within your call to `mutate()`:

```
mutate(people, age_in_20 = as.numeric(age) + 20)

    names age age_in_20
1    anup  26        46
2   minal  27        47
3   surya  28        48
4 sheetal  30        50
```