# Numeric data gives error non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

New to R.

I have a dataframe called SortedDF with 125143 observations and 5 variables

```
Head(SortedDF)
      number Retention time (min) Charge      m/z              Group
28637  98481             16.87978      2 350.1859 Progenesis_peptide
82465 DVQLPK             14.35000      2 350.2022      PEAKS_peptide
81468 DVQLPK             14.32000      2 350.2027      PEAKS_peptide
76662 DVQLPK             14.33000      2 350.2028      PEAKS_peptide
77423 DVQLPK             14.36000      2 350.2029      PEAKS_peptide
73768 DVQLPK             14.27000      2 350.2039      PEAKS_peptide
```

I want to match peptides based on their m/z similarity using lead command.

```
MatchedDF <- SortedDF %>% mutate(matches_with_next_row = (abs(("m/z") - lead("m/z")) < 0.01))
```

While coding another database, this code worked perfectly. However right now, I get the error message saying

> Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `matches_with_next_row = ... & Group != lead(Group)`. Caused by error in `("m/z") - lead("m/z")`: ! non-numeric argument to binary operator Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

When checking

> class(SortedDF$"m/z")
>
> > (1) "numeric"

I checked following threads without succes:
[x non-numeric argument to binary operator while using mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162105/x-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-while-using-mutate)
--> tried '' around m/z without succes

Other threads mainly talk about other problems than mine. If anyone has an idea on what I am doing wrong, please tell me.

Comment: `"m/z"` is a character constant in R.  If your variable name really is `m/z`, then you need to enclose it in backticks, not quotes, to refer to in in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"m/z"` is a non-numeric character, whereas `m/z` with back ticks refers to a data variable of the particular column:

```
MatchedDF <- SortedDF %>% mutate(
  matches_with_next_row = (abs((`m/z`) - lead(`m/z`)) < 0.01)
)
```

It is recommended to not use special characters for column names to make these expressions much easier to write.

Comment: So 'm/z' did not work. I changed m/z back to m.z without back ticks or quotes and this worked. Thanks for the input

Comment: use back ticks instead of single quotes